# Spring boot application getting shutdown after starting

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am working with **Azure cosmos DB (NoSQL API)** and have set below configs for connection and creating Async client.

```
@Bean
    public CosmosClientBuilder getCosmosClientBuilder() {
        return new CosmosClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .key(key)
                .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.SESSION)
                .preferredRegions(List.of("Central US"));
    }

@Bean
    public CosmosAsyncDatabase cosmosAsyncDatabase() {
        return getCosmosClientBuilder().buildAsyncClient().getDatabase(getDatabaseName());
    }
```

Code where this config is used :

```
 @Autowired
    public StatusByIdLocationDaoImpl(CosmosAsyncDatabase cosmosAsyncDatabase) {
        log.info("DATABASE : " + cosmosAsyncDatabase.getId());
        this.cosmosAsyncContainer = cosmosAsyncDatabase.getContainer("status_test");
        log.info("CONTAINER : : " +  cosmosAsyncContainer.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<FeedResponse<Data>> getStatusEvents(Instant startTime, Instant endTime, String continueToken, int batchSize) {
        CosmosQueryRequestOptions cosmosQueryRequestOptions = new CosmosQueryRequestOptions();
        try {
            log.info("CALLING THE DB");
            return cosmosAsyncContainer.queryItems(query, cosmosQueryRequestOptions, Data.class).byPage(continueToken, batchSize).toIterable();
        } catch (CosmosException cosmosException) {
            log.error("Error occurred while fetch the status events : {}", cosmosException.getDiagnostics());
            log.error("Error", cosmosException.fillInStackTrace());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now when I am running the application in local, I works fine but when I am deploying the application k8s, I am getting below issue, where it starts the application and immediately closes (Shutdown) it.

I am not sure what is wrong with configuration as it is working on local.

I have also tried doing the same with repository pattern but getting same error as above

Here is the *dependency used for cosmos*:

```
implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-spring-data-cosmos', version: '3.30.0'
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Comment: Edited the query

Comment: Why do you think the issue is related to CosmosDB when you deploy on Kubernetes? Is there any error that tells you that it's a CosmosDB issue?

Comment: There are no error for the same as I have dig into the issue, I think its related to something related to spring boot